# How can I horizontally center two columns of list items(with or without Bootstrap)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please excuse me, this problem is difficult to explain and I'm having a very difficult time finding a solution.

I have a list of items which I would like to divide into two columns.  I would like to keep the list item text left-aligned so that the asterisks you see remain aligned in a sort of column, themselves.  However, I would like the two columns of list items to always be centered in the viewport.  Furthermore, the list items contain text of variable lengths, so using bootstrap's text-center jumbles them and doesn't keep the li columns intact.  What it actually is, is each item in the list is a link with a FontAwesome icon next to it.

Example
[image]

As it stands, my code looks similar to this.

```
<ul class="col-xs-12">
  <li class="col-xs-6">*List Item</li>
  <li class="col-xs-6">*Some List Item</li>
  <li class="col-xs-6">*A List Item</li>
  <li class="col-xs-6">*One List Item</li>
  <li class="col-xs-6">*This List Item</li>
  <li class="col-xs-6">*Im A List Item</li>
</ul>
```

This is similar to how they render now:

|*List Item          *List Item          |
|*List Item          *List Item          |
|*List Item          *List Item          |

This is how I would like them to render:

|      *List Item      *List Item      |
|      *List Item      *List Item      |
|      *List Item      *List Item      |

I should also mention that I would like them to remain fluid.  I don't have a fixed width for them.

Also, I have tried offsetting columns and it doesn't seem to work the way I want. I have also tried using CSS columns: 2 and I couldn't figure out how to make them work the way I want. I assume that I will have to write some js for this but I was wondering if anyone had a fix using either Bootstrap or CSS or a mix of both.

Please excuse me if there are any problems with my question.  This is my first post here at Stack Overflow.

Updates:

So far, the best looking solution, and the closest to what I am looking for comes from this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/eo40fOMNVlRt9gBT4us4?p=preview

The only problem with this is that if each li>a has different text value(and they do, but I have a limit on them of 18 characters), the FontIcons(asterisks) that appear to the left of each , won't horizontally align.  However, if you have a look at that plunker, those list columns area always exactly centered in their half of the viewport, regardless of browser window size.  I appreciate the thought behind a lot of the ideas below, but even if I limit the length of the  string value, there may still be issues with bootstrap's columns being just too short and therefore causing the text string to overflow to the next line on small viewport widths.  Furthermore, locking these into columns forces each one to, at certain widths, not be centered.

I'm thinking it may be time for me to start working on a script for this.  Please, any other ideas are appreciated.

Comment: *Please excuse me if there are any problems with my question. This is my first post here at StackOverflow.* You are doing it right. Keep it up. But it is encouraged to show us a demo/code snippet which shows the example. Not required much for this question but to be noted for upcoming questions.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/hao05vfcr0cgKTraGI1E?p=preview

Comment: Tried encasing the text in a div and setting margin-left?

Comment: Thanks so much, sir.  The only problem is that the list items can be variable lengths.  I should have specified that.  That's what's making this difficult.  I can't use text-center, as it produces something like: http://plnkr.co/edit/D1DpM8j7bKPwmLIVPbVH?p=preview   The problem with that is that I would like the FontAwesome images next to my links to remain in a column, themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<ul class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8">
<li class="col-xs-6">*List Item</li>
<li class="col-xs-6">*This List Item</li>
<li class="col-xs-6">*I Am List Item</li>
<li class="col-xs-6">*List Item</li>
<li class="col-xs-6">*A List Item</li>
<li class="col-xs-6">*Im An Item</li>
</ul>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Mh0IxzzdRE8ZmeX9gNWJ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use bootstrap classes for columns, so you have something like this:

```
<li class="col-xs-6"><div class="col-xs-3"></div><div class="col-xs-9">*List Item</div></li>
<li class="col-xs-6"><div class="col-xs-3"></div><div class="col-xs-9">*List Item Second</div></li>
<li class="col-xs-6"><div class="col-xs-3"></div><div class="col-xs-9">*List Item Third</div></li>
<li class="col-xs-6"><div class="col-xs-3"></div><div class="col-xs-9">*List Item Some other len</div></li>
<li class="col-xs-6"><div class="col-xs-3"></div><div class="col-xs-9">*List Item</div></li>
<li class="col-xs-6"><div class="col-xs-3"></div><div class="col-xs-9">*List Item</div></li>
```

I separated every "li" in two subcolumns: 3 and 9. You can change as you like, but to remain sum of them is equals 12 (bootstrap style). So you set what you like:

```
<li class="col-xs-6"><div class="col-xs-4"></div><div class="col-xs-8">*List Item</div></li>
...
```

I made a plunker where you can try what you like: [PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/934pIyvD116Cjv0AMxjq?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

If you can drop old-browsers support there is a pure css solution:

> [CSS3 Multiple Columns](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

```css
ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a>Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a>Item 5</a></li>
  <li><a>Item 6</a></li>
  <li><a>Item 7</a></li>
  <li><a>Item 8</a></li>
  <li><a>Item 9</a></li>
  <li><a>Item 0</a></li>
  <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a>Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```